# Java limit length integer

Tags: java, validation, integer

I am new in Java and I need some help.

Can someone tell me how I can set limit length to integer = 6 in this code.

For example

```
id = 124973 

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}
```

Comment: You can have `setId` have `this.id = id % 1000000;`.

Comment: What do you want to do when the "length" is not 6 or less?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One way to do it is like this:

```
public boolean checkLength(int id, int length) {
    return 0 == (int)(id / Math.pow(10, length));
}
```

**EDIT:**

As per @EliSadoff comment below, you can also do something like this:

```
public boolean checkLength(int id, int length) {
    return Math.log10(id) < length;
}
```

You can then simply call this function like this:

```
checkLength(123456, 6);
```

Comment: Wouldn't `Math.log10(id) < length` work just as well but be more explicit?

Comment: @EliSadoff Right! I din't think about it. :) I'll post and *Edit*. Thanks

Comment: No worries! Great answer!

Answer (score 3):

"String.valueOf(id).length()" - checks the length of a int variable, which you receive in setId method parameter.

```
public void setId(int id){
    if(6 >= String.valueOf(id).length())
       this.id= id;
    else
       //do something if the received id's length is greater than max
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In your `setId` method add a check:

```
if (id >= 1000000 || id < 0) {
   throw new IllegalArgumentException("id must be max 6 digits and cannot be negative");
}
```

Comment: Most of the answers just assume that you would want somekind of default when you set a "wrong" id... I think that's really bad practice which will result in surprises down the line.

Answer (score 2):

validate the inp before assigning it

```
public void setId(int id){
    if(id>0 && id<=999999){
        this.id= id;
    }else{
        this.id= 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In java numbers like int don't have the length. Although Integer is a class, there is no length() function -- see the Java docs. So, to find the length, you have to convert Integer to String using `String.valueOf(Integer_value)`. So, you can do like below:

```
Public void limit(Integer a) {
if(String.valueOf(a)<=6) {
    //do your logic
}
else {
//printout Integer length limit exceeded
}
}
```